# What does the word "context" usually mean in structures?

Tags: c, data-structures, ffmpeg, scope

I'm trying to build an application using some of ffmpeg's libraries and I'm noticing many data structures with the word "Context" in them.

You can see some here http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/classes.html

I don't understand the use of the word "context" in this.. context.

Any hints as to what it generally means?

Comment: Translate to "state", maybe that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at documentations you provided it seems related to the context of a particolar codec so that every `SomethingContext` encapsulates

- the structs necessary for that particular codec (headers and so on)
- the available operations when wortking with that codec (which may vary according to the complexity of the codec itself)

something like "when working with H264.."

Answer (score 2):

In C, a struct is usually the means by which instantiation of an object occurs.

An API will have a new() type function, which will allocate one of these 'context' structures and provide a pointer to it.

That pointer is then typically passed to any public functions from that API.

e.g.

```
struct btree_state
   *btree_state;

btree_new( &btree_state );
btree_new_element( btree_state, pointer_to_user_data );
```

This way we can have multiple instances of the given object.  We select which one to use by the state pointer we pass into the API functions.

Answer (score 2):

For FFMpeg, think of "context" to be kind of like an object instance (c++, java "this").  A context is created when a format session is opened within FFmepg, when an input device is opened, a codec, and for an output device